# c# División de cadenas con linq

Tags: c#, lista, linq

Hola buenas noches tengo el siguiente caso quería ver si ven alguna forma mas optima de realizar esta separación de texto a lista

tengo el siguiente texto en una variable

```
var text =  " /START
Name    Jesus
LastName    Perez
/END
/START
Name    Carlos
LastName    Gutierrez
/END
/START
Name    Luis
LastName    Gutierrez
/END
"
```

Tengo que separar el text en registros pero conservando los TAGS de separacion(/START - /END) use `linq` y lo realizo asi:

```
var listInformation = text.Split(new string[] { "/START"+Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Con la instrucción anterior divido la cadena de texto en registros pero para splitear lo hago por el tag /START por lo cual me lo elimina , como la lista debe quedar completa con todos los tags despues se lo agrego de esta forma

```
var listFull= listInformation.Select(x => string.Concat("/START"+Environment.NewLine, x));
```

y esto ya me devuelve en listFull el texto orinal separado con los tags

elemento 1:

```
/START
Name    Jesus
LastName    Perez
/END
```

elemento 2:

```
/START
Name    Carlos
LastName    Gutierrez
/END
```

...
Alguna forma de realizarlo con mejores practicas o mejor rendimiento, saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes solucionar con una sola instrucción de expresiones regulares:

```
foreach (var match in Regex.Matches(text, @"\/START[\s\S]+?\/END"))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Bloque encontrado: {match}\n\n");
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVBNS8NAED1nf8UQPKSo6d0iftQiSFtKU/DQ9DCkY1xIdnVmU1pLf3ucRgoq6LCHmeXNm/deIZeFZ2rbRqwrIdtJoHpgvk/pgrYhnVPZVMij7RuTiPVOBsYUFYrAjH3JWJu9iSRgsAUw4dq7agdZ4CNRUAa4htu4ny3u5gszxZpA64mkETNGCaefGTF9mP5o@mB@YYfIlf8JfmyCJf5rYdzY/@Cx6j/p3Xi7hglal0gneLkC5FJ6JlJP0YsGhMUrJBtkqDFoax1oILRNJ8eRJDk6vFCD@ZeIZS55tjq/ybtLPSXqmKKh5uYrSp/ZBhpbR8lZfF/594aAXOFdYA3uCvbdlUPuchf3Brp4MPoObfsJ)</kbd>.

Si lo quieres como una expresión LinQ, podría ser algo así:

```
var bloques = Regex.Matches(text, @"\/START[\s\S]+?\/END")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value);
```

Comment: muchas gracias el regex.matches me parece la mejor opcion, me pondre a estudiar mas sobre expresiones regulares,... saludos